# Where does software installer look for application icon

Tags: software-installation, debian

I'm building a .deb file and cannot find out where the Ubuntu software installer looks for an application icon.

This is not runtime that comes from the .desktop file.[.deb opened by software installer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QdrD.png)

I'm talking about when you open the .deb file via software installer, some .deb actually have the application icon showing up instead of the default gear in a box thing.

I would like to take the creation of this .deb to a more professional level by having the application icon appear during install.

Comment: Thank you! You should post that as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu Software gets the metadata and icon from [Appstream](https://wiki.debian.org/AppStream).

> AppStream is a cross-distro XML format to provide metadata for software components and to assign unique identifiers to software.

- [How to get your package data into appstream](https://wiki.debian.org/AppStream/Guidelines)